# perl case insensitive switch as variable?

Tags: regex, perl

In perl, I would like to be able to do this:

```
$switches = "is";
$regexp = "\\d";
if ($string =~ m/$regexp/$switches) {
 do something...
}
```

In other words, how can I make "$switches" optional at run-time?
(The user can choose from a variety of options for the search)

Comment: what kind of switches? you mean command-line args? `./foo.pl arg1 -arg2=foo`?

Comment: @Marc B, Match operator flags

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if ($string =~ /(?$flags:$pattern)/) {
   ...
}
```

Note: This won't work if `$pattern` is a compiled pattern (i.e. produced by `qr//`) rather than a string since it's the flags passed to `qr//` that affect a pattern compiled with `qr//`. You would have to pass the flags to `qr//` rather than `m//`.